# OpenCV on Android Core.inRange Error and APP crash

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV on Android. But the function:

```
Core.inRange(img, new Scalar(127, 127, 127), new Scalar(127, 127, 127), img);
```

crashes on the second call with "Fatal signal 8 (SIGFPE) at 0x00002a01 (code=0)"?

Answer (score 0):

That crash should not happen, might be a bug.

But I don't think setting lower and upper bounds with the same values make sense, you should choose some values that make sense and are within the **img** dimensions.

Also make sure **img**, or whatever Mat you use in the last parameter, is of type CV_8U.

Comment: The image type is CV_8UC1 and the dimensions w=640, h=480.